# How to use berkshelf with vagrant without the vagrant-berkshelf plugin

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-solo, berkshelf

I am new to berkshelf and have tried a few samples using vagrant-berkshelf plugin. From the time i got to know that the vagrant-berkshelf plugin is going to get deprecated, i have been wondering if there is anyway i can use the berkshelf with vagrant without using the vagrant-berkshelf plugin. Please let me know how i can go about it.

Comment: Berkshelf core development team member announced the official deprecation process of Vagrant Berkshelf on January 28, 2014. 

He explained in the announcement like this:

"Until we work out an official deprecation schedule, the team will continue to be responsive to issues and pull requests. It is likely that Vagrant Berkshelf will continue to be supported until the release of Berkshelf 4."


the announcement can be found here: https://sethvargo.com/the-future-of-vagrant-berkshelf/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf

From the site you will need to run:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf --plugin-version '>= 2.0.1'
```

Once the Vagrant Berkshelf plugin is installed it can be enabled in your Vagrantfile

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.berkshelf.enabled = true
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a alternative where i do not have to use the vagrant-berkshelf plugin.

Comment: An alternative like https://github.com/fgrehm/ventriloquist or does it still have to use Berkshelf?

Comment: It still needs to use Berkshelf..:-(